# Are there known issues with the C function crypt()?

Tags: c, encryption, passwords, crypt

I use crypt() to encrypt passwords for a project of mine. When the password is chosen by the user, it's encrypted like this:

```
password = crypt(<password chosen>, <user's account name>)
```

The problem is when the user logs in using their password. If what they type doesn't match their password, it should enter this if check:

```
if (strcmp(crypt(<what user types in as password>, <user's account name>), <user's encrypted password>)) {
   //...
}
```

It doesn't in one certain scenario. Let's say their password is 'asdf'. If they enter 'asdf' with any random trailing characters, such as 'asdffffff' or 'asdf339sfd', it still accepts the password. It seems to ignore everything after 'asdf'.

Is this a known issue with crypt? Is there another way to encrypt passwords?

Comment: Do you mind sharing a [mcve]? Your description sounds wrong.

Comment: I would suspect your *input* method, not `crypt()` (which works in a different way than you seem to assume, by the way - so you better read its [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html)).

Comment: @ Downvoters: this actually has enough information for a complete answer and I am writing one now.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain your passwords were getting truncated to _four_ characters?  Might it have been eight characters instead?  Eight is a lot more explicable than four, you see.

Comment: @zwol Well, that's not the only reason to downvote this. Another reason is not reading the specification for the function and checking for errors. A third is not being responsive to comments.

Comment: @klutt Enough of the documentation surrounding `crypt` and friends is old enough, cryptic enough, or just-plain-wrong-anymore enough, that I really don't blame OP for being confused.  Not responding to comments is a fair criticism, though.

Comment: @zwol Being confused by inaccurate documentation is one thing. Not reading it is another thing. Afaik there's no documentation that states that the second argument should be the username. :)

Comment: @zwol And as you said, it's pretty strange that it's four characters and not eight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second argument to `crypt` is not supposed to be the user's account name.  It's supposed to be a *setting string*.  Setting strings look like this:

```
$2b$07$fQuDK3TaQP4sw6IX6iVcTw
```

The `$2b$07$` part tells `crypt` which password-hashing algorithm to use, and the string of random characters that follows is the [salt](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)).  The salt must be *different* for each user, but it is not supposed to have any correlation with the user's account name.  It doesn't technically have to be random, but it's critical that it be different for each user, and it needs to change every time the user changes their password, so best practice is to use a long string drawn from a cryptographic PRNG.

When you authenticate a user who has logged in before, you use the stored hashed password as the setting string:

```
char *new_hash = crypt("password typed in", "stored hash");
if (new_hash && !strcmp(new_hash, "stored hash")) {
    // user has successfully logged in
}
```

This works because the stored hashed password always begins with the setting string that was used to create it in the first place, and `crypt` is coded to look only at the setting-string part.

(Also note the null check; some implementations of `crypt` can fail and report failure by returning a null pointer.)

When you create a new account or change a password, you have to generate a new setting string.  If you have the function [`crypt_gensalt`](https://www.mankier.com/3/crypt_gensalt), use that:

```
char *new_setting = crypt_gensalt("$2b$", 0, 0, 0);
if (new_setting) {
    char *new_hash = crypt("user's new password", new_setting);
    // ...
} else {
    // halt and catch fire
}
```

If you don't have `crypt_gensalt` you have to implement it yourself, unfortunately.  (To make matters worse, some Unixes have the `crypt_gensalt` whose documentation I linked to above, and others have [a different version](https://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/3c/crypt_gensalt), with the same name, doing the same job, but taking different arguments.  Time to dust off your Autoconf skillz!)

---

Now you know all of that, I can explain why

```
password = crypt("password chosen", "user's account name");
```

appeared to work but truncated the password.  Your user account names probably begin with at least two alphanumeric characters, right?  Like, `"Ma[ya]"`, or `"zw[ol]"`?  Unfortunately, any two alphanumeric characters make a valid setting string ... that selects one of the oldest and least secure password-hashing algorithms known to science, [descrypt](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.hash.des_crypt.html#format).  (It was pretty good when it was invented ... in the mid-1970s.  Nowadays, [it can be cracked by brute force](https://crack.sh/des_crypt/) no matter what the password is.)  One of the many problems with this algorithm is that it truncates all passwords to eight characters.  `asdf` and `asdfhjkl` hash to different things, but `asdfhjkl` and `asdfhjkl1234` hash to the same thing.

The cure for this is to use `crypt_gensalt` or equivalent to select a modern algorithm.  All the modern algorithms accept arbitrarily long passphrases.

Comment: *"It's supposed to be a setting string."* -- hmm, pretty sure it's supposed to be a two-character salt.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: There are different `crypt` routines in different libraries/platforms. And a two-character salt would not be very strong.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli If your `crypt` only supports descrypt, yes, but then you need to upgrade it before someone brute-forces your entire shadow file :)

Comment: @EricPostpischil hmm, of course, I am talking about `man 3 crypt` here.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Hmm, that must not be _this_ [`man 3 crypt`](https://www.mankier.com/3/crypt)...

Comment: @zwol ah, I see, that's `crypt` from libcrypt. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @zwol indeed I was looking at `crypt` from `unistd.h` (simply typed `man 3 crypt` on my terminal).

Comment: @MarcoBonelli You might also want to read [`crypt(5)`](https://www.mankier.com/5/crypt) from the same source, if you haven't encountered non-DES hashes before in a Unix context.  They're not new.

Comment: @zwol yeah I know they're quite old stuff, I was just under the impression that OP was talking about `unistd`'s `crypt`.

Comment: That's a legit assumption given the OP is asking about "C function crypt()"

Comment: Thing is, "crypt from `unistd.h`" and "crypt from libcrypt" may well be the same function.  The linker doesn't care which header file had `extern char *crypt(const char *, const char *);` in it, and whether you get the implementation from `-lcrypt` or the implicit `-lc` or somewhere else, it probably supports more than just DES nowadays.

Comment: @zwol Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I'm looking at a highly modified stock ROM multi-user dungeon code and hadn't written the crypt portion myself - it was written by the original creators of the code base, so I assumed it was written properly - guess not! I will update using your suggestions. Thanks.